# How to call CoreLocation from different Views

Tags: ios, swift, oop, architecture, core-location

I have Two Views (one table, one collection). In each View's Cell, there is a button that when tapped should get the user's current location and pass it into a variable to be used in a Deeplink.

I can achieve this by implementing `CoreLocation` in both views,but am trying to adhere to DRY and therefore write a Class or implement it in AppDelegate **once**, and call it when a user presses the button from either View's Cell.

I've seen similar questions which recommend using the Singleton pattern, or to use `NSNotificationCenter` and observe for when the button is pressed.

Any ideas for an optimal implementation in this case?

Comment: The simplest way is just to implement the location manager in your app delegate and have it expose a property for the current location. Simply update this property from the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. A slightly "cleaner" approach is to create another object to serve this role, allocate it in the app delegate and pass it to the view controllers (or use singleton if you must)

Comment: @Paulw11 thx for answer.. I've implemented CLLocationManager in AppDelegate, and created a function to get the User's current location - and then populate the property for currentLocation. However, if I instantiate the AppDelegate in another View, I cannot access the function I wrote. I suppose I am not doing this correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: appDelegate is a singleton. Don't instantiate it. Get a reference using `UIApplication.sharedApplicatiin.delegate`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want something like this:

```
final class UserLocationFinder: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let instance = UserLocationFinder()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    // implement the code necessary to get the user's location and
    //   assign it to currentLocation 
}
```

Then in the code that needs to know the current location, you can:

```
if let currentLocation = UserLocationFinder.instance.currentLocation {
    // the current location is known
```

This way you satisfy DRY because the code is only in this one class and you satisfy the single responsibility principle (SRP) because you aren't overloading the `AppDelegate` with extra responsibilities...